# How to search for tracks using the soundcloud Sdk iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, sdk, soundcloud

I have read the soundcloud's sdk documentation for iOS and it doesn't seem to say anything about searching for songs, though it talked about listing tracks from an existing soundcloud user. So are there any resources out there or examples ? Thanks a million !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use this format:

`https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks?q=SEARCHTEXT&format=json`

Just remember, if the user enters a space, you have to replace it with `%20`, you can achieve this by

`NSString *search = [originalSearch stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];`

Then, just request the JSON data like this:

```
[SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks?q=%@&format=json", search]] usingParameters:nil withAccount:[SCSoundCloud account] sendingProgressHandler:nil responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
```

My final code looks like this:

```
 NSString *search = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

[SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks?q=%@&format=json", search]] usingParameters:nil withAccount:[SCSoundCloud account] sendingProgressHandler:nil responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    NSError *jsonError;
    NSJSONSerialization *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

    if (!jsonError && [jsonResponse isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        self.searchQuery = (NSArray *)jsonResponse;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);

    }

}];`
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: Any chance you could convert this to Swift? I am having a very hard time using the sound cloud api with my swift application

Comment: @Will Jamieson I'm not really using swift, but I'll try!

Comment: That would be awesome. I currently just resorted to making HTTP Get requests and ignoring the wrapper sdk